# Handling sorted and filtered collections coming from APIs in a redux store

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns, collections, redux, store

[Redux guidelines](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers) suggest to

> think at an app's state as a database

and to ***prefer key-based objects over arrays*** when it comes to store resources. This makes totally sense, since it simplifies 99% of the most common use cases when dealing with collections: search, find, add more, remove, read...

Unfortunately the downsides show up when it comes to keep a filterable and sortable collection of resources synched with APIs responses. For example a typical request:

```
GET /users?status=active&orderBy=name&orderDir=asc&lastID=1234&limit=10
```

will return a filtered, sorted and paged, list (array) of users. Typically the reducer will then take this array do something like:

```
users: {...state.users, keyBy(action.payload, 'id')}
```

This will merge new data with previously fetched ones **breaking the computation done from APIS**. 
The app must then perform a second, client-side, computation on the collection to reconstruct the expected list. This results in:

- redundant computation (redo something that has been already done by the server)
- duplication of logic (same filtering and sorting code deployed both client-side and server-side)
- maintenance coast (client app developers must take the extra burden to keep filters and sort logic synched every time it changes on the backend to guarantee consistency)

Another downside, if you are implementing a sort of infinite loading, is that you must keep track of the lastID, since there is not way do deduce what is the last loaded id after results have been merged.

So the question:

What's the best approach to design stores and reducers that must deal with sorted/filterd/paged data fetched via APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On of the common approaches is to keep object-index map and sorted object-list in separate structures.

Example reducer (using [ramda](http://ramdajs.com/)):

```
function reducer(state, action) {
  if (action.type == 'USERS_LOADED') {
    return r.merge(state, {
      userIndex: ramda.reduce(
        (acc, user) => ramda.assoc(user.id, user, acc),
        {},
        action.payload
      ),
      userList: ramda.map(
        ramda.prop('id'),
        action.payload
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Example connect selector:

```
connect(
  state => ({
    users: state.userList.map(id => state.userIndex[id]) // this reconstructs users in original order
  })
)(...)
```

You can also use open-source project [DataScript](https://github.com/tonsky/datascript).

> An immutable in-memory database and Datalog query engine.
>
> DataScript is meant to run inside the browser. It is cheap to create,
>   quick to query and ephemeral. You create a database on page load, put
>   some data in it, track changes, do queries and forget about it when
>   the user closes the page.
>
> DataScript databases are immutable and based on persistent data
>   structures. In fact, they’re more like data structures than databases
>   (think Hashmap). Unlike querying a real SQL DB, when you query
>   DataScript, it all comes down to a Hashmap lookup. Or series of
>   lookups. Or array iteration. There’s no particular overhead to it. You
>   put a little data in it, it’s fast. You put in a lot of data, well, at
>   least it has indexes. That should do better than you filtering an
>   array by hand anyway. The thing is really lightweight.

It has nice [Javascript API](https://github.com/tonsky/datascript/wiki/Javascript-API). Usage [example](https://github.com/hden/reduxscript) (a bit outdated). [Discussion](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/318) by redux core team.

Comment: This looks like an effective solution. Do you know any other approach?